# jQuery if else on dropdownlist MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web app in `mvc5` in which i have a dropdownlist with static values i created a function in jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#role").change(function () {
            $("#txtusrname").attr('readonly', false);
            $("#txtpass").attr('readonly', false);
            $("#rdiogoogle").attr('checked', false);
            $("#rdioerp").attr('checked', true);
            $("#btngoogle").hide();
            $("#btnerp").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is working fine but now i want to make textboxes readonly if the selected value of dropdownlist is `"Trainer"` what i need to do is use if else statment in the script, please do help me out in this

Comment: `if ($(this).val() === 'Trainer') { .... } else { .... }` (assuming the `value` attribute of the option is `value="Trainer"` (note also you should be useing `.prop()`, not `attr()`)

Answer (score 0):

Select the selected using the `:selected` selector and jquery `find()` to get the value use `val()` ,use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#role").change(function () {
           if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "Trainer" ) {
            $("#txtusrname").prop('readonly', false);
            $("#txtpass").prop('readonly', false);
            $("#rdiogoogle").prop('checked', false);
            $("#rdioerp").pro('checked', true);
            $("#btngoogle").hide();
            $("#btnerp").show();
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sir this is not working

I have 2 textbox 2 radio button and 2 button if user select trainer in dropdown textbox must be become read only and radio button 1 should be checked and button number 1 should be visible and 2 should be disable

Comment: is the alert triggering?

Comment: but when i delete `alert("Trainer");` and replace with my code nothing is happening

Comment: i hope you put the if statement in the on event ?

Comment: `if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "Trainer" ) {
$("#txtusrname").attr('readonly', true);
            $("#txtpass").attr('readonly', true);
            $("#rdiogoogle").attr('checked', true);
            $("#rdioerp").attr('checked', false);
            $("#btngoogle").show();
            $("#btnerp").hide();

}`